# How to get input steps ouput in jenkins-pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I used in my pipeline a input steps as you can see below :

```
input(
         message : "some message",
         parameters: [
          [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
            choices: string ,
            description: 'description',
            name:'input'
         ]
        ]
      )
```

I wanted to use the name input that I configure to get the value put in the input like this  ${input}, but it didn't work. I also tried to put it in a var like this :

```
def reg = input : messages : "", paramaters: [...]
```

But It doesn't work either, so I don't understand how I can get the param that the user chose and didn't find how to do in the do.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use this code:

```
def userInput = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'some message', parameters: [
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: string, description: 'description', name:'input'],
    ])
    VARAIBLE = userInput
```

It's work For me.
If you need add more `ChoiceParameterDefinition` code should look like that:

```
def userInput = input(id: 'userInput', message: 'some message', parameters: [
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: string, description: 'description1', name:'input1'],
    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: string, description: 'description2', name:'input2'],
    ])
    VARAIBLE1 = userInput['input1']
    VARAIBLE2 = userInput['input2']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tested it like the other answer and both work. Tanks too for the second example with several ChoiceParameterDefinition it help me !

Comment: HI @Nab, how to add dropdown paramter

Answer (score 8):

When using `ChoiceParameterDefinition` remember to define choices as string delimited with `\n`. You can assign value returned by `input(...)` step to a variable and use it later on. Take a look at following example:

```
node {
    stage('Test') {
        def reg = input(
            message: 'What is the reg value?', 
            parameters: [
                [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', 
                    choices: 'Choice 1\nChoice 2\nChoice 3', 
                    name: 'input', 
                    description: 'A select box option']
            ])

        echo "Reg is ${reg}"
    }
}
```

In this example I define a single select with 3 options. When I run this pipeline,  I get this popup to select one of three options:

[image]

I pick the first one and pipeline finishes with following console output:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test-pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] input
Input requested
Approved by admin
[Pipeline] echo
Reg is Choice 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works well !  With respect to your advice rergarding the fact of defining a list of choices as string delimited by "\n", my var "string" contains choices separated by "\n" that i get from a list. Thanks for the help !